# libreoffice writer renders dejavu font differently. Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, libreoffice-writer

Here is how it is rendered on Ubuntu :

[image: ubuntu dejavu]

Here is how it is rendered on Arch linux :

[image: arch linux dejavu]

Why is it different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those characters are not found in that font, and fontconfig has picked two different fonts to get the glyphs from; make sure that VLGothic is installed on the Arch system.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how I can find out which font is used when a character is not present in it? And why do you suggest VLGothic?

Comment: Character Map can tell you if a glyph isn't present; simply switch to the font in question, go to the character, and right-click to see which font is providing the glyph. I suggest VLGothic because that looks like VLGothic.

Comment: You are right. On ubuntu, it uses NanumGothic and on arch it uses AR PL ... fonts.